# Mouse click callback in MATLAB for line plot

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-figure, axes

If I want to read location of the mose click on some image I can do it using `callback` action.

```
function[]=FooBar
Img=imshow(FooMatrix,'callback',@(s,e)ImageClickCallback());

 function ImageClickCallback(objectHandle,~)
  axesHandle  = get(objectHandle,'Parent');
  coordinates = get(axesHandle,'CurrentPoint');
  coordinates = round(coordinates(1,1:2))
 end
end
```

It works well for images but now I have axes with lines only. I tried to set the `callback` routine to the appropriate `axes` or the `line` but I got the error message

> `Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback`
>
> `Error using hg.figure/set
>   The name 'callback' is not an accessible property for an instance of class
>   'figure'.`

---

Background:
I am trying to create GUI with line plot, say `y=f(x)` enabling user to select points on the line. Idea is to read the `[x,y]` coordinates of the mouse click and highlight the point `[f'(y),y]` or `[x,f(x)]`, where `f'` is inverse function to `f`. Something like `Data Cursor` function does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`callback` isn't a valid property of a line object. You'll want to set the [`ButtonDownFcn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/button-down-callback-function.html) property of the line object.

```
h = plot(1:3, 'ButtonDownFcn', @(s,e)ImageClickCallback()
```

The `ButtonDownFcn` property is also available for most of UI elements (including axes)

```
set(gca, 'ButtonDownFcn', @mycallback)
```